# $k$ such that interval of solution of a Cauchy problem contains 0 and it is the biggest possible

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, cauchy-problem

So I have the following Cauchy problem :

$$ y' = \frac{e^{-y^2}}{y}$$
$$ y(0) = k \neq 0 $$
I want to find k such that the interval of definition is the biggest possible and containing 0. 
Now, I started by solving the Differential equation separating variables, and I get the following solution:

$$ \vert y(x) \vert = \sqrt{\log{(2x + e^{k^2})}}$$

However which condition do I impose to find the k such that I get the biggest interval of definition? I only know that I must have:
$$ 2x + e^{k^2} > 0$$
$$ 2x + e^{k^2} \ge 1 $$

But after that I am stuck. Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: You can't. The bigger $k$, the larger the domain $x\ge(1-e^{k^2})/2$. There is no maximizing $k$.